Jira filter to find the last created ticket
I am trying to create a filter in jira to match/find the last created ticket - only one ticket which was created last.
I came up with the following filter but it matches the last day. If yesterday there was no ticket created the result of this filter would be empty - but the filter I am trying to create must guarantee to return one last created ticket. How can I make it to find and return the last created ticket?
project = "<project_name>" AND reporter = <reporter_id> AND created >= -1d ORDER BY created DESC

Some background info why I need to get the latest ticket. This is needed to build a test result summary chart in jira dashboard. We use jira-xray tool to report testrun results, jira-xray creates test executions a kind of jira ticket basically and there are dashboard/chart templates to build test result summary I just need to pass a filter which matches one - last created test_execution_id and it will do the job for me.

For the query you have, I don't think you need
AND created >= -1d

You can simply run this command and it will give you list of all the tickets in descending order i.e.the most recent ticket will appear on top.
project = "<project_name>" AND reporter = <reporter_id> ORDER BY created DESC

However, we cannot use limit in jql so that is an issue here. Although, if you want only 1 ticket here then you can do it in two ways:

Using Dashboard Gadgets where you can use gadgets like Filter Results gadgets on a Jira dashboard and configure them to show only one issue. To do this the steps are: Create a filter with the JQL
project = "<project_name>" AND reporter = <reporter_id> ORDER BY created DESCAdd a dashboard gadget (e.g., Filter Results).In the gadget settings, set the "Number of Results" to 1, ensuring only the latest issue is displayed.
Using Third-Party Plugins where you can use plugins like ScriptRunner or JQL Tricks for Jira, these add advanced functionalities like limiting results. For example, with ScriptRunner, you can write a Groovy script that fetches only the most recent issue.

